# TCP Client/Server with Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

This may be a very basic question/design but I am struggling with the correct method to handle the system I am going to define here.

I have a system with a single client (PC) that will connect to an embedded Linux board (Raspberry Pi) via TCP/IP protocol.  This will be a command/response system where the PC will ask for something and the raspberry PI will respond with the results.

For Example:
   CMD => Read/Return ADC Channel X

RSP => ADC Channel X Data

For this type of system I have already defined a packet protocol that will allow for this interaction.  My problem is how to handle this on the Raspberry PI.  I envision having a single thread handling the TCP connection; placing incomming data into a thread safe queue and pulling outgoing data from a thread safe queue.  Then the main thread would poll the queue periodically looking for data.  When data is found the command would be processed and a response will be generated.  All commands have a response.

The main thread will also be doing other time critical tasks (PID control loop) so it cannot wait for incoming or outgoing data.

My guess is this type of system is fairly common and there is probably a good approach to implementing this type of system.  I am very new to Linux programming but I have been programming highly embedded systems (No OS) forever.  Just struggling with the correct approach for this type of design.

Note I chose TCP/IP because it handles retying in case of failure.  In my case every command has a response so UDP could be used if it makes the design easier/more flexible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also should have mentioned that the number of commands and size of packets will vary greatly.  So this system needs to run the entire time the application is running.  There just might not always be a client connected.

Comment: Is the critical thread going to have this data anyway? Or will it have to get/compute it to react to the request? If the data will already be available, then the thread that handles the client can just do a simple read/process/write loop and no need for the queue. The "process" portion would just access the data from some thread-safe storage.

Comment: The question is a little broad as it stands. You will get higher quality answers if you make an attempt, and write a post about why you find it unsatisfactory.

Comment: @jxh I agree with you totally just did not know where to start.  I think I will attempt the select approach detailed below by sashang and see if that works.  I will post a follow up if it does not meet my needs.

Comment: On linux look into `epoll`, it's more performant than `select` and requires less storage in userspace. I implemented [a server library using epoll](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools) and was happy with it's performance (even though the HTTP layer has some unaligned memory access, it's running quite smoothly). Multi-threading is a question of preferences and requirements. Does RasPI have multi-cores or threads to it's ARM CPU? I suspect a single thread might work better if you keep to an evented design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to avoid threads if I can and only use them if I have to because they make debugging the program harder. They turn a determinsitic problem into a non-deterministic one. So my initial approach would be to see if I can do this without a thread and still achieve concurrency. This is possible using `select` which will notify your main program when there is something on the socket that needs to be read. Then, when there is something on the socket, it can read the data, process it, and wait for the next event. Problems with this approach is if the computation on the received data takes longer than the acceptable time wanted to process the next element of data, you could end up with a backlog of unprocessed data on the socket. If this is going to happen then you can go ahead and run the receive loop in thread, and the work function in another thread, or fork a new process and deal with a copy of the data from the new process.

Comment: Hmm I like this approach.  Being a deeply embedded developer I never use threads.  I was not aware of the select approach.  This could work if select does not block.  I will reasearch now.

Comment: Since OP was referencing linux, I feel `epoll` might be a better option... what do you think?

Comment: @Myst: yes epoll works if the kernel supports it. I've never used epoll directly but used libevent which wraps epoll.

Comment: I marked this as a solution because it does seem to work as needed,  I will look into epoll as well.  i need to see if raspbian (jessie) (based on debian) supports it.

Answer (score 1):

the ultra classic linux approach is to have a listener program that forks a new copy of itself for each new client. Linux even has a built in demon that does that for you (initd - although that might have changed with all the systemd stuff). Thats how sshd, telnetd, ftpd all work. No threads

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned there will only be one client.  My issue is more to do with actually handling the incoming data so that it does not disturb my main thread with time critical tasks.  Hope that makes sense :)